# Are there any Japanese handwriting input app

Tags: languages

Are there Android app that recognize Japanese handwriting words and translate into Japanese text? (In another word, I handwriting some Japanese words on the android phone and it translate into Japanese text.)

Answer (score 2):

yeah there's [Google Handwriting Input](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.handwriting.ime&hl=en) available on PlayStore. get it.

Answer (score 0):

Tried Google Translate App? It can do such things[image]